# Microsoft access text filter

Tags: ms-access, filter

I'm currently constructing a database for users. the issue I am stuck with lies with the email field, as users are able to enter their email I then have a column after which is set up to contain the users email provider, for example

The first column will contain

Abc123@abc.com

But as the the second column, in this case I want it to just display the text after the "@" symbol, so it should read

Abc.com

How would I go about setting this filter, or is it even possible?  having to enter this manually would make the database inefficient.

Comment: Try with regular expressions. You'll find tons of e-mail validation patterns (and you can use one of them to extract the provider part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split, mid, instr any number of text functions. For example:

```
Provider = Split(Email & "","@")(1)
```

Or

```
Provider = Mid(Email & "", Instr(Email & "","@")+1)
```

This is assuming you have used a text field for email, if you have used a hyperlink field, and I recommend that you do not, it gets more complicated.

Comment: Sorry thought i had it working, but i didnt. where am i to enter this expression

Comment: I would say that the after update event of the email control would be best. Change the word 'Provider' to `Me.NameOfProviderControlHere`

Comment: SHOULD I DESIGN THIS AS A QUERY?

Comment: Why are you shouting at me? You can view or update the provider in a query using the Mid line, or, as I suggested, you can alter the user interface to update the provider when data is entered.

Comment: +1 I would have initially used the Mid/Instr method, but until now didn't realise you could add (1) to the end of a split without having to define a separate array string. I really like that method : )

Comment: Sorry Remou didnt realise caplock was on :$ i wasnt sure how to use either of these methods so i went with

`Right(Trim([NewEmail]),Len(Trim([NewEmail]))-InStr(1,[NewEmail],"@"))`

and this worked fine